# Set builder notation depending on precondition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I wonder how I should use the set builder notation for a set $A_{s_j}$ if the definition depends on the precondition $s_j = s_?$:

\begin{align}
A_{s_j} &= \{ a \mid a \in A_{s_i} \text{ of the last known state $s_i$ in the sequence} \} &&\Leftrightarrow &&s_j = s_? \\
A_{s_j} &= \{ \text{all possible actions for all available components in $s_j$} \} &&\Leftrightarrow &&\text{else}
\end{align}

I also thought about using an Iverson bracket, but I'm not really happy with this either. Moreover, I struggle with the definition of the else case—looks quite verbose.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** To give some context, this is part of a work in software testing. The system under test (SUT) is being modelled as non-deterministic finite automaton (NFA), based on the observed behavior of the graphical user interface (GUI).

$s_j$ denotes an already visited state, whereas $s_?$ is the unexplored state of the SUT. $A_{s_j}$ represents the set of all possible GUI actions within the state $s_j$. For instance, a click (action) on a button (component) is part of $A_{s_j}$ iff that action can be executed in $s_j$.

Comment: What kind of "action"? And how does $s_j$ have components? (Also, this looks more like class-builder notation at first sight) _ If you want $X=\{\,y\in Y\mid \phi(Y)\,\}$ if $P$ and $X=\{\,z\in Z\mid \psi(z)\,\}$ if $\neg P$, you might write $X=\{\,t\in Y\cup Z\mid (P\land t\in Y\land \phi(Y))\lor (\neg P\land t\in Z\land \psi(t))\,\}$

Comment: So do you have $A_{s_1}\subseteq A_{s_2}\subseteq\dots$ or something?

Comment: Added some context, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is often easier to use the text to explain "We define $A_{s_j}$ to be such and such if this and that, and otherwise $A_{s_j}$ is defined to be this and that". However, if you are really insistent on using set builder notation, which again I will recommend against, I would write something like this:

$$\{a\mid s_j=s\rightarrow\text{condition one}\lor s_j\neq s\rightarrow\text{condition two}\},$$
So if $s_j=s$ we get the first condition to hold, and then we take such and such elements, and if not, then we take some other condition for the elements.

Let me again reiterate, that mathematics is based on clarity. The clearer you are to the reader, the better. Formulas are unambiguous, but they can be hard to parse for human beings, which is why an accompoanying text is always recommended, if not better at times.

Comment: May I join in recommending against? `;-)`